# Normalization of time series data for input into Neural Network, values will vary over time

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, normalization, standardization

I was reading up on how to normalize stock time series data for input into a neural network. What I've seen suggests things like min-max normalization and z-score normalization. The issue I see is, say you're doing a time series of 10 years. The stock goes up over time, and if one was using the first 9 years as the training set, one would normalize on that. The min and max would be used, and what you'd end up with is small numbers that get bigger over those 9 years. Wouldn't this be less than ideal?

If this is an issue, what would be a better way to normalize this? Say the data included the usual OHLC, and also some technical indicators like moving averages, RSI, etc.